# Why cannot subsribe a method to a datatable's click event with the lambda construct?

Tags: typescript, datatables, angular5

I'm working with datatables (datatables.net) in angular 5 and I was subscribing a method to respond to a click event on a `tr` like so:

```
const tableRef = this.table;    // bound datatable and router to scope 
const routerRef = this.router;  // so I can use them inside the callBack
this.table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function (e) {
    const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    const data = tableRef.row($tr).data();
    if (data !== undefined) {
        routerRef.navigateByUrl(`/some/url/details/${data.id}`);
    }
});
```

It's almost identical to the sample on datatables.net's
website. The things is that, later I decided to change my code like the one below:

```
this.table.on('click', 'tbody  tr', this.rowClicked(this.table, this.router));

//...

private rowClicked(table, router: Router) {
    return (e) => {
        const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
        const data = table.row($tr).data();
        if (data !== undefined) {
            router.navigateByUrl('/some/url/details/`${data.id}`');
        }
    }
}
```

and... for my surprise it didn't do anything, not even a blink! Then I went ahead
and put a `console.log('row clicked');` inside the lambda (if it's ok to name it that way, 
I'm really new to typescript) and it got printed any time I clicked on a `tr` but `data`
was always `undefined`. I even changed `table` variable for `$("#my-datatable-id").DataTable()`
and still no luck. After several minutes I decided to `git diff` the file and realized that the only
difference was the way the callBack was getting constructed (using the keyword `function`) so I did that and changed the lambda for:

```
private rowClicked(table, router: Router) {
    return function (e) {
        // same as before
    }
}
```

Guess what, it worked! It fetched the `tr`'s data like a charm. So, could any one
explain to me why when using the lambda I wasn't able to fetch the `data` from the row and 
when using the `function` construct I was to. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know Angular, but I presume that `this.table.on` is passing a custom `this` context to the callback that is necessary for `$(this)` to work as you intend.  When you use an arrow function, the context passed by `this.table.on` is ignored and `this` instead refers to the object on which `rowClicked` was called, so you get a different result.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm not mistaken, it's because of [Javascript Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures) around `this`.

These two do not produce the same `this`:

```
this.table.on('click', 'tbody tr', function (e) {
  // "this" is what you think it is
});
```

vs

```
this.table.on('click', 'tbody  tr', this.rowClicked(this.table, this.router));

private rowClicked(table, router: Router) {
  // "this" should be window
  return (e) => {
    const $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
    const data = table.row($tr).data();
    if (data !== undefined) {
        router.navigateByUrl('/some/url/details/`${data.id}`');
    }
  }
}
```

You should be able to fix it a simply as:

```
this.table.on('click', 'tbody  tr', () => this.rowClicked(this.table, this.router));
```

or

```
this.table.on('click', 'tbody  tr', () => { return this.rowClicked(this.table, this.router); });
```

Because the above creates... well what I'll call, *an anonymous function on this* then the inner call `rowClicked` is scoped correctly (not window).

Comment: Hi there, thanks for replying. I changed as you said and still doesn't work